# Javascript split by $, but not $$

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var s= "this is inline $\alpha$, $$not$$";
```

How can I replace the `'$'` by `'%%'` but not the `'$$'`.

Such that the output is

```
var s= "this is inline %%\alpha%%, $$not$$";
```

I was thinking

```
s.split('$').join('%%')
```

But I need to split by only one dollar not two.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a callback and a greedy quantifier:

```
s.replace(/\$+/g, function(match) {
    return match.length === 1 ? '%' : match;
});
```

Comment: +1 for the first approach, but the second approach is subject to incorrect output in the event of an odd number greater than one of `$`, or if the temporary replacement is present elsewhere in the string.

Comment: @Vulcan: True... I guess I will remove that then :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this:

```
.replace(/(^|[^$])\$([^$]|$)/g, "$1%%$2")
```

Since `$` is alone, there should be no `$` before and after it, so we can try matching one non-`$` character before and after, and replace them back in the replacement string.